# Where is config.log Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (gnu/Linux 3.13.0-30-generic *86_64)

Tags: linux, r, gcc

I tried to install R package "RMySQL" on the R server. 
    `Install.packages('RMySQL', type='source')`
But there is an error message:

```
Installing package into ‘/data/rstudio5/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 165363 bytes (161 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 161 Kb
* installing *source* package ‘RMySQL’ ...
** package ‘RMySQL’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RMySQL’
* removing ‘/data/rstudio5/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RMySQL’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpoOnKGL/downloaded_packages’
```

When I try to find the config.log on PUTTY:
    `less config.log`
It says no such file or directory.

Where is the config.log? and how can I check it? There are some related topics on Google but not feasible in this case.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1441752

Comment: Is `gcc` installed? Try typing `which gcc` in bash and `"/usr/bin/gcc"` should appear.

Comment: I have a similar error when installing the stringi package
`"configure: error: C preprocessor "g++ -E" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details"` Did you find where config.log is located?

Comment: In case someone else is having similar package installation issues related to the  C compiler. Based on [this discussion related to RODBC](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2012-April/001840.html), I solved my issue by installing the package from the Cran repository at the shell prompt: `sudo apt-get install r-cran-stringr` (you probably set up the cran repository when you installed R). You could try `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmysql`.

Answer (score 2):

There is usually a ./build directory off of where configure is sitting. Mine was there.

In your case that should be
/tmp/RtmpoOnKGL/downloaded_packages/build

I hope that helps.